# How to give a markerClusterGroup a zIndexOffset in Leaflet.MarkerCluster

Tags: leaflet.markercluster

In my project several layers of clustered data are shown. Layering should be consistent, i.e. if the user moves a layer up, it's markers and marker groups should always move above other layers markers and marker groups.

When building regular L.marker layers, I can pass a marker a `zIndexOffset` to control what z-index layers are layered at. This works nicely and also works for L.marker's that were not included in a marker group.

When using clustered layers and building them using `markerClusterGroup`, using a `window.L.divIcon` in the options, it seems that the z-index of marker groups of different layers are haphazardly set.

Is there a way to set a zIndexOffset for cluster groups?

Comment: did u solved this issue?

Comment: nope but luckily no one using the application complained yet :-)